# Finding Height with a specific angle

Tags: geometry

I am building a sloped table and I need to determine the height of one side. Here are my dimensions. The tall side has two legs at a height of $55$ inches, the top where the tabletop attaches will be cut at a $60^\circ$ angle. The Distance from where the tall legs attach to the next set of legs is $34$ inches. The next set of legs will be also cut at a $60^\circ$ angle, however I am not sure how to calculate what height the second set of legs should be. I have added a image to explain. Hopefully some one can help. [image]

Comment: $55-34\sin(60^\circ)$

Comment: Is the 60 degree angle the one that the table top makes with the larger leg, or the one the table top would make with the "floor" if extended?

Comment: @BrettFrankel could you place this as a answer so I can choose it thanks.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The 60degree angle is the slope of the two legs.

Comment: @Anders: That doesn't tell me which angle you are measuring (I'm no carpenter): the one on "top left" or the one on "bottom right".

Answer (score 1):

Since Brett Frankel never placed his comment in this box, I'll do it: the height is $55−34\sin(60^\circ) \approx 25.5$